# Self removable directive in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to create application which will allow me to append and destroy repeatable elements, but i encounter a problem.

Firstly here is my directive to append elements:

```
myApp.directive("addWatcher", function($compile){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind("click", function(){
            angular.element(document.getElementById('watchers-space')).append($compile("<Watcher></Watcher>")(scope));
        });
    };
});
```

And it contains this div-button:

```
        <div ng-click="remove()">X</div>
```

And of course here is watcher directive:

```
myApp.directive('watcher', function() {
    return {
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
            $scope.remove = function() {
                $element.remove();
            }
        },
        templateUrl: 'watcherDirective.html'
    };
});
```

The problem is I can add many of "Watchers" but i can remove only the last one added, and also firstly created on page load. What am i missing with implementation to create opportunity to remove every created "Watcher" element?

Comment: They all share the same `$scope`, so the last watcher overrides it with "remove this element". So no matter on which remove you click, it is overridden with the removal of the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the @devqon comment i resolved it in this way:

```
myApp.directive('watcher', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
            $scope.remove = function() {
                $element.remove();
                $scope.$destroy();
            }
        },
        templateUrl: 'watcherDirective.html'
    };
});
```

And now everything works

Comment: better to destroy scope as well. ```$scope.$destroy();```